# Move from a sprint to new sprint

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, jira-agile

I have 100 issues in my sprint(Ex:Sprint 10). Now i want to move 50 issues to new Sprint(Ex:Sprint11) without creating new sprint manually.

As a workaround, I have selected that 50 issues and rightclick then doing bulk change. There i have "Change Sprint" available. If i give 11 then it creates sprint11 automatically and move the issues to Sprint11. But in some cases if i give any random numbers it says "Sprint must Exits:44"

Is this the correct way to bulkmove to new sprint? If so what is the reason to occur the error?

Thanks in advance

KCB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is because it is not intended to work in this way. You cannot just randomly create Sprint XXX when you don't have Sprint XXX-1.

Just create a new empty Sprint and then bulk-copy the issues over to it.
You could also ask for a feature request from Atlassian as to have a button called "Create new sprint with the selected issues". Go to support.atlassian.com.